# Month Day Year Error

Tags: c#, datetime, exception

I have a variable containing a string which corresponds to a date and time and I am attempting to convert the string into a `DateTime` object. The variable of the date, `newTime` correlates to the following format - `MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss`, however I am having trouble as I keep receiving an error;

> The string was not recognised as a valid DateTime.

Here is the code for the method:

```
public static DateTime ConvertToDateTime(string newTime)
{
     //newTime = "06/25/18 21:56:43"
     return DateTime.ParseExact(newTime, "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: Add your code not images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are using 12-hour parsing for 24-hour time. Use `HH` instead of `hh`. See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) for more details.

Comment: Wow, such a simple solution, ha! - Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it's days of debugging followed by changing a few characters.